# How to create a function in MySQL from an SQL script, JDBC or Spring JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm looking for a way to create a function in MySQL preferably from a script (**executed from Java**) but standard JDBC or Spring's JdbcTemplate would work as well.

I've managed to successfully create the function from mysql command-line console using:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION test() RETURNS double DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN 63;
END$$
```

But since `DELIMITER` in not a valid SQL syntax I get an exception when running it from a script:

`[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$`

When I try to create it from Spring JDBC template using

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE FUNCTION some() RETURNS double DETERMINISTIC\n" +
            "BEGIN\n" +
            "RETURN 63;\n" +
            "END;");
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'CREATE FUNCTION some() RETURNS double DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN 63;
END' at line 1`
```

Does anyone know how to go about?

Comment: Did you found a solution to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jdbc to do that, but on your script  don't declare any delimiter and then put your own one to separate functions or procedures declarations
your script will look like :

```
CREATE FUNCTION do_something() RETURNS double DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN 63;
END;;
CREATE FUNCTION do_other_thing() RETURNS double DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN 63;
END;;
```

and the code to use will be like this after getting your sql script into a StringBuilder

```
 String[] sql = stringBuilder.toString().split(";;");
    for (int i = 0; i < sql.length; i++) {
                     statment.executeUpdate(sql[i]);
                }
```

I hope this ill help !

Answer (score -2):

when you use Spring Framework, please use Hibernate Framework for connecting data.

Comment: Sure that's no problem but would that really help me in this case?

Comment: Do you have any arguments to backup this definitive statement?